# How C++ is calculating offset address when i declare array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, offset, memory-address

Though string is dynamic so it will not have any definite size so when i get s[1] before s[0] how C++ will calculate its offset address.

For example int a[2]

```
0000:1000    a[0]
0000:1004    a[1]
```

Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s[2];

    cin>>s[1];
    cout<<s[1]<<endl;

    cin>>s[0];
    cout<<s[0]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array of strings is an array of string objects, which are of fixed size and effectively contain *pointers* elsewhere where the strings actually reside.

Comment: Thanks but i'm having another question how can i store and read my data(array of strings) using file (i.e using fwrite/fread).

Comment: That is indeed a different matter. Basically, you need to come up with the way to serialize them, which strongly depends on what do you intend to do with them. You can zero-terminate them, length-prefix, store index of offset to beginning of strings and strings separately (like the described phenomenon in memory), etc.

Comment: sir can you please write that as a program and post it in comment.

Comment: @Bala: That's quite a bit of code, and depends almost entirely on how you need to do things.  (As he said, there are different ways of doing it that work for different needs.)  You're basically asking for custom software at this point, which falls outside the scope of SO.

Answer (score 6):

`std::string` does not in its memory layout actually contain its characters. It simply contains a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory and keeps track of its size. Just like `std::vector` doesn't actually store its elements inside its members. Instead, it has a pointer to the actual elements situated "on the heap". S

So regardless of the number of characters a string has, its size (meaning `sizeof (std::string)` )is a compile time constant.